# computer's turn to play the guessing game

Tags: python

The point of the game is to guess the number, but the roles are reverse.I guess the number and the computer selects the right number. I finish the list and it works, but I need help on one parts. How would I add the option after entering the number if the guess was too high or Low? like if the com said 5 , then I could say "its too low or too high". thanks in advance.

```
    from random import randint
    def computer_guess(num):
        low = 1
        high = 100

        guess = randint(1,100)
        while guess != num:
           print("The computer takes a guess...", guess)
           if guess > num:
              high = guess
           elif guess < num:
               low = guess + 1

           guess = (low+high)//2    

       print("The computron guessed", guess, "and it was correct!")
       print(" I computron won the battle!")

 def main():
       print("I am computron, I accept your guessing game!")
       num = int(input("\n\nChoose a number for the computer to guess: "))
       if num < 1 or num > 100:
           print("Must be in range [1, 100]")
       else:
           computer_guess(num)

if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

Comment: When you copy paste your code in here, you can highlight it and press control+K or the `{ }` button to format it; You should not do manual indenting because you can make a lot of mistakes.

Comment: Yeah it was a struggle. Should I redo it?

Comment: Yes please, just copy-paste directly from source and control+K after highlighting :)

Comment: did I do it correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from random import randint

def computer_guess(num):
    low = 1
    high = 100

    guess = randint(1,100)
    while guess != num:
        print("The computer takes a guess...", guess)
        if guess > num:
            high = guess
            print ' Computron guessed higher'
        elif guess < num:
            low = guess + 1
            print 'Computron guessed lower'

        guess = (low+high)//2    

    print("The computron guessed", guess, "and it was correct!")
    print(" I computron won the battle!")

def main():
    print("I am computron, I accept your guessing game!")
    num = int(input("\n\nChoose a number for the computer to guess: "))
    if num < 1 or num > 100:
        print("Must be in range [1, 100]")
    else:
        computer_guess(num)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    while True:
        ask = raw_input('Do you want to play again [y/n]:')
        if ask.lower() =='y':
            main()
        else:
            print 'bye'
            break

#Output

I am computron, I accept your guessing game!


Choose a number for the computer to guess: 56
('The computer takes a guess...', 25)
Computron guessed lower
('The computer takes a guess...', 63)
 Computron guessed higher
('The computer takes a guess...', 44)
Computron guessed lower
('The computer takes a guess...', 54)
Computron guessed lower
('The computer takes a guess...', 59)
 Computron guessed higher
('The computer takes a guess...', 57)
 Computron guessed higher
('The computron guessed', 56, 'and it was correct!')
 I computron won the battle!
Do you want to play again [y/n]:y
I am computron, I accept your guessing game!


Choose a number for the computer to guess: 44
('The computer takes a guess...', 40)
Computron guessed lower
('The computer takes a guess...', 70)
 Computron guessed higher
('The computer takes a guess...', 55)
 Computron guessed higher
('The computer takes a guess...', 48)
 Computron guessed higher
('The computron guessed', 44, 'and it was correct!')
 I computron won the battle!
Do you want to play again [y/n]:n
bye
```